# react-native-webview Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.11

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, kotlin

I initialized a react-native app with react-native init xxx and installed the latest(v4.1.0). Android Studio could not complete sync. it says:

[image]

When I run react-antive run-android from console, it says something similar.

[image]

I tried to wget the kotlin gradle plugin, it was not there. :'(

[image]

#### How to reproduce?

- Just initialize a react-native(0.58) app
- Run `yarn install react-native-webview` .  // version 4.1.0
- run `react-native run-android`

So this is a deadlink:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.11/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.11.pom

I find it's here.
https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.11/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.11.pom

Please Note version 1.3.20 is also available.
https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.20.pom

Please help :'(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Delete `.idea` folder and `.iml` in android directory
2. In Android Studio -> Build -> `Clean`
3. File -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`